# How to show application content and not firebase hosting documentation when deploying?

Tags: html, angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

I setup my firebase using the documentation but when I run "firebase deploy", It shows hosting documentation and not my application. The tutorials I've seen do the exact same thing and It works for them.
I have tried editing the index.html that comes with firebase public directory and that seems to work as long as its simple text but when I copy my Angular app.component.html or when I copy some other component's html, It comes blank. I am not sure If I need to edit the public directory's HTML I would assume It would automatically update as I am changing my project's HTML. It is suppose to display my project's html template on firebase using firebase hosting.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I deploy my angular project to firebase

`ng build --prod` - to build production package

`npm install -g firebase-tools` - Install firebase tools(if not already installed)

`firebase login` - login to your account(this will open webpage, you need to allow firebase with your google account)

**IMPORTANT**

`firebase init` - run this command in project top level path. Select **Hosting** and press enter. change public directory to dist and make sure all the files/folders of your package are in dist folder directly.
`Y`(Yes) to configure as single page app, and `N`(No) to overwrite index.html

`firebase deploy` - to deploy project

**Note:**

Make sure you have `index.html`(**Your angular file**) in `dist` folder directly, and also check what is your public directory in `firebase.json`. It should be like `hosting > public > dist`

Angular cli generate files like this `dist/YOUR-PROJECT-NAME-FOLDER/index.html`, Make sure it is like directly in dist e.g `dist/index.html`

Comment: I do all the steps upto firebase deploy but it does not deploy my project it deploys firebase hosting documentation for some reason.

Comment: @Mohammad Answer updated, see if it solves your problem

Comment: I copy pasted my projects index.html in dist index.html. 
My firebase.json looks like 

{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}




and My dist folder looks like dist/project then index.html. It is different the naming convention has dist/project then inside is html there is no dist then project folder then index.html. They put dist/project in one and then index.html.

Comment: @Mohammad Do one thing, change **public** to **dist** in `firebase.json` and your package files should looks like `dist/index.html` and `dist/ALL-OTHER-FILES`

Comment: i changed public: "dist" and getting page not found error by firebase.

this is the error i am getting 
You may have deployed the wrong directory for your application. Check your firebase.json and make sure the public directory is pointing to a directory that contains an index.html file.
And not sure how to point the right directory that contains which index.html? There are multiple